# Fatal error: cannot use stdClass as array

Tags: php, stdclass

I've inherited some code from an ex-colleague and as it has recently been put into production it is causing us some issues. I'm not a php developer so apologies if this appears vague but it has fallen to me (don't ask!).

We are calling a function `getLoan()` to pre-populate an application form from an existing application. This should return an array, but I am receiving the stdClass error.

```
$result = getLoan(); //this is the line that is erroring
if (isset($result->GetResult->Debtor->Addresses->Address[0])) $current_address = clone     $result->GetResult->Debtor->Addresses->Address[0];
else $current_address = clone $result->GetResult->Debtor->Addresses->Address;

if ($result === false)
{
  echo("No LID given");
  die;
}
$attr = 'selected';
```

and the function:

```
function getLoan() {
//globals
/*
global $client;
global $test;
global $result;
*/
global $thisurl;

if (isset($_GET['LID'])) 
         $pLoanID = $_GET['LID'];
else 
         return false;
$test = array(
        "pLoanID" => $pLoanID,
);

//print_r($Address); //print address object as a test
//send to gateway starts**********
$url = "https://www.blahblah.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));

try {
    $result = $client->Get($test);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    //header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "/application-form-new");
    print_r($e);
    exit;
}

$thisurl = "continue-app?LID=" . $pLoanID;
if (isset($result)) return $result;
else return false;
}
```

How can I assign the returned value from the function to $result as an array?

Many thanks

Comment: you say `getLoan()` is supposed to return an array, yet you are using it as an object right under its call `$result->GetResult`

Comment: use type cast like (array)$result

Comment: Ok in that case do I need to convert it to an object?

Answer (score 1):

```
array = json_decode(json_encode(object),true);
```

Comment: `$result = json_decode(json_encode(getLoan(),true));` expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: json_decode() returns array if you pass true as a second parameter. Basically you pass json encoded object to json_decode with true as a second parameter and it will return array of that object. that is how  i interchange between array and object

Comment: @ajguk  you are doing it wrong please check the format of function calls and open and close braces

Comment: `$result = json_decode(json_decode(getLoan()),true);` - same error

Comment: My apologies. I am now getting "Trying to get property of non-object" - for $result